# HTML Button returning “Cannot POST /index.php”

Tags: php, html, curl, oauth-2.0, stripe-payments

I am trying to activate the index.php file which is a function for Stripe Connect. However, when I press the button on my HTML page to activate the function, it results in `Cannot POST /pages/index.php`. Both the HTML and PHP files are in the same folder. What I am trying to do is automate this: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#token-request

**HTML CODE**

```
<form action="input.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" class="bg-transparent text-grey-darkest font-bold uppercase tracking-wide py-3 px-6 border-2 border-grey-light hover:border-grey rounded-lg" value="Continue">
</form>
```

**PHP CODE**

```
    <?php
  define('CLIENT_ID', 'ca_xxxxxxx');
  define('API_KEY', 'sk_xxxxxxx');

  define('TOKEN_URI', 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token');
  define('AUTHORIZE_URI', 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize');

  if (isset($_GET['code'])) { // Redirect w/ code
    $code = $_GET['code'];

    $token_request_body = array(
      'client_secret' => API_KEY,
      'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
      'client_id' => CLIENT_ID,
      'code' => $code,
    );

    $req = curl_init(TOKEN_URI);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '' );
    curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($token_request_body));

    // TODO: Additional error handling
    $respCode = curl_getinfo($req, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $resp = json_decode(curl_exec($req), true);
    curl_close($req);

    echo $resp['access_token'];
  } else if (isset($_GET['error'])) { // Error
    echo $_GET['error_description'];
  } else { // Show OAuth link
    $authorize_request_body = array(
      'response_type' => 'code',
      'scope' => 'read_write',
      'client_id' => CLIENT_ID
    );

    $url = AUTHORIZE_URI . '?' . http_build_query($authorize_request_body);
    echo "<a href='$url'>Connect with Stripe</a>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: I think you're a little confused here. The PHP file you have there looks like it is for [finalizing the OAuth connection](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#redirected) — it's the page that you would set as the `redirect_uri`, which Stripe sends the user to after they authorize the connection. But when your 'Continue' button is pressed, you should actually be redirecting the customer(set `window.location.href` for example) to the OAuth URL, not trying to load that page.

Comment: Separately, you can't automate this, you need to redirect the user to the Stripe form and have them fill out the form and get redirected back to your server, that's just how Express accounts and OAuth works.